# Using Lua with C++

Tags: c++, lua, embed

I'm trying to embed lua in a c program, but I'm having problems to compile the code. I have installed everything lua 5.2 related in synaptic and when tried to compile this:

```
extern "C"{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lua5.2/lua.h"
#include "lua5.2/lauxlib.h"
#include "lua5.2/lualib.h"
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    lua_State *lua_state;
    lua_state = luaL_newstate();
    lua_close(lua_state);
}
```

and compile using

> g++ main.cpp -llua

show the folowing errors

> Could not find -llua

what do?

Comment: use `-L/path/to/lib`

Comment: Please decide: Shall that be a C or a C++ program? BTW: You can compile Lua both as C as well as C++, though I would leep it C. Also, neither `<stdio.h>` nor `<string.h>` should be wrapped in an `extern "C"`-block.

Comment: @redFIVE Like this? g++ main.cpp -L/usr/lib/lua/5.2/ -llua . Still not find -llua

Comment: Is there a `liblua.so` in that directory?

Comment: @Deduplicator No o.O . there is a rdd.so and no liblua.so anywhere im my pc. Why not? I have installed everything lua5.2 disponible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools you can use to find the proper compiler / linker switches for a library.

In particular, with a proper installation of the lua5.2 libraries you can use

```
pkg-config -libs lua5.2
```

On my system it outputs

```
-llua5.2
```

Use this, or the output of pkg-config (backticked) as your linkers argument.

Of course, pkg-config can also tell you the -CFLAGS for the package with

```
pkg-config --cflags lua5.2
```

The man page is quite readable.